# Android studio with java

Tags: back4app

I have trouble getting data here from database there isn't data, 
Data is not displayed outside of the method.
Could you please help me?

```
List<Person> Refresh() {
    Person p = new Person();
    ParseQuery <ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(NAME_DATABASE);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList , ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < scoreList.size(); i++){
                    p.setId(scoreList.get(i).getInt(Key.ID));
                    p.setName(scoreList.get(i).getString(Key.NAME));
                    p.setAge(scoreList.get(i).getString(Key.AGE));                       p.setDate_start(scoreList.get(i).getString(Key.DATE_START));
                    p.setMonth_number(scoreList.get(i).getString(Key.MONTH_NUMBER));
                    p.setPropriety(scoreList.get(i).getString(Key.PROPRIETY));
                    p.setPrice(scoreList.get(i).getString(Key.PRICE));
                    p.setGender(scoreList.get(i).getString(Key.GENDER));                       
                    persons.add(p); //there is find data
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    return persons; //here there isn't data (size=0)
}
```

Comment: Hi! (Just checking) Have you already taken a look at the API Reference of your app? There's a customizable code that might help you to get the data from the class that you want to.

You can access it at Dashboard > API Reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple really. You are returning persons outside the findInBackground() method.

```
    else{
     Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
     //Return here after the else statement
     return persons;
    }
```

Note : you might want to make persons a global variable or else android studio will tell you to declare it as a final variable.